# F# finding only prime numbers

Tags: f#, primes

I'm recently new to F# so please bear with me. The problem i have is I'm trying to find only prime numbers.

I've write this code:

```
  let isPrime n =
    let rec check i =
    i > n/2 || (n % i <> 0 && check (i + 1))
       check 2;;

let listNums = List.filter isPrime >> List.length;;

 let nums = [ 16; 17; 3; 4; 2; 5; 11; 6; 7; 18; 13; 14; ];;

let countPrimes (x:int) = x |> List.ofSeq |> listNums;;
```

trying to call

```
countPrimes nums;;
```

but this is failed with message:

```
The type 'int' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: you don't need `countPrimes` at all - `listNums nums` should work (if `isPrime`works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to countPrimes separately. Enough to remove and will work:

```
let isPrime n =
    let rec check i =
        i > n/2 || (n % i <> 0 && check (i + 1))
    check 2

let nums = [ 16; 17; 3; 4; 2; 5; 11; 6; 7; 18; 13; 14; ]

let listPrime lst =
    lst |> List.filter isPrime

nums |> listPrime |> printfn "%A"
```

Out:
[17; 3; 2; 5; 11; 7; 13]

Link:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/nVXwZ5

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution

```
let isPrime n =
let rec check i =
    i > n/2 || (n % i <> 0 && check (i + 1))
check 2;;

let listNums = List.filter isPrime >> List.length;;

let nums = [| 16; 17; 3; 4; 2; 5; 11; 6; 7; 18; 13; 14; |];;

let countPrimes (x:int[]) = x |> List.ofSeq |> listNums;;

countPrimes nums;;
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

x |> List.ofSeq

seems to be the problem to me.  You are passing an int into a function that requires a list.  List.toSeq changes a list into a sequence. You want the function countPrimes to take a List of integers, not simply an integer.  Although Carsten is right, listNums already takes a List of integers (edit: and computes the value you want provided isPrime is correct).